# Iterate over (print) TypeScript map with Angular Expression

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, typescript, google-maps-api-3

I wish to iterate over this map so I can show the markers (value object) on the map and call actions with the id (key.

My map looks like this:

```
let markerMap: Map<string, GMarker> = new Map<string, GMarker>();
```

The key is the `id` where the value is the `GMarker` object:

```
type GMarker = { long: number, lat: number };
```

Now I would like to iterate over this map with an Angular expression.

I have tried different approaches using custom Pipes:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'keys' })
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value, args: string[]): any {
        let keys = [];
        for (let key in value) {
            keys.push({ key: key, value: value[key] });
        }
        return keys;
    }
}
```

The map is being filled, now I have to show it in hmtl:

```
<ul>
     <li *ngFor="let m of markerMap | keys"></li>
</ul>
```

Typescript:

```
 this.markerMap.forEach((value: GMarker, key: string) => {
            console.log(key, value);
        });
```

> 595e58eb27362d6b873cf1b7 Object { long: 4.39751, lat: 52.65264 }
>
> 595e58ec80ea98f3080036fc Object { long: 4.39751, lat: 52.65264 }
>
> 595e58ec6814c9194fea9240 Object { long: 4.39751, lat: 52.65264 }
>
> 595e58ec71693848ee4f2230 Object { long: 4.39751, lat: 52.65264 }

Thanks in Advance.